# add Event Listener to button Titanium, link to window

Tags: javascript, titanium, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a button that when clicked, goes to a window. I have already created the window and also created its own .js file.  I cannot get the button to work, any suggestions on where I am going wrong? Here is my code:

```
var platformWidth = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;
var platformHeight = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;


var playButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: "Play",
    style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BORDERED,
    center: {
        x: platformWidth * 0.5,
        y: platformHeight * 0.5
    }

});

win.add(playButton);

playButton.addEventListener('click' , function() {

    playButton.url='playWindow.js'
 });
```

I know that the playWindow.js works as I have tabs working on the pages that are linked.

playWindow.js

```
var platformWidth = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth; 
var platformHeight = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight; 
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow; 
var testTextField = Titanium.UI.createTextField({ 
    backgroundColor: 'white', 
    borderStyle: Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED, 
    center: { 
       x: platformWidth * 0.5, 
      y: platformHeight * 0.3 },
    width: platformWidth * 1 
}); 

win.add(testTextField);
```

I am wondering whether having the different windows as different files is a good idea. They don't seem to be working correctly.  How come there isn't a simple code for buttons, like there is for tab (ie: window: 'playWindow')?

I got a -1 for my question saying it doesn't show any research effort.  I have spent the last 4-5 hours trying to find a solution to something so simple.. maybe it is too simple. All I want to be able to do is have a button on one page, that when clicked, goes to another...

TIA
Ange

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
    playButton.addEventListener('click' , function() {
    var w = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        url:'playWindow.js'
    });
       w.open()
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: I have tried this, i still doesn't work.. well, it works, but it doesn't link properly to the actual playWindow.js (has different background etc.

Comment: var platformWidth = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;
    var platformHeight = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;
    var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

    var testTextField = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
     backgroundColor: 'white',
     borderStyle: Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
     center: {
      x: platformWidth * 0.5,
      y: platformHeight * 0.3
     },
     width: platformWidth * 1
 
     });

    win.add(testTextField);

Comment: you could set the background color and image according to your desire

Comment: win.backgroundColor='black';

Comment: yes, but then the 'play' tab and the 'play' button are going to two different pages instead of the same page... IYKWIM

Comment: This is getting confusing to follow.  It appears you want the 'play button' to shift to the 'play tab' rather than opening a completely different window without the tabs on it.  Yes?

Comment: @Martin, yes that is what I would like to do. I don't want to create a new window, rather go to an existing one.